# Internet Explorer 8 remembering me (keeping cookies) in "New Session"

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, session

From what I gather (e.g. http://tutorialfeed.blogspot.com/2009/06/ie-8-perk-access-multiple-gmail.html ) one can get a new IE8 window clean from older cookies and independent of what's going on in other windows.

Alas, when I try that web sites still remember me in the window of the new session.

Any ideas what's wrong in my setup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I want to have separate cookies I usually run IE, along with Chrome and Firefox.  This way I can have totally separate things going on without having the browser's behavior be identical.  I don't think IE8 can have the short term history info saved for one but not for other windows.

Comment: I do need the multiple sessions inside IE8, for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It'll only help with session cookies, but you can use the New Session command from the File menu to get a new instance of IE. You can also set up a shortcut that automatically starts a new session by adding the `-nomerge` option to the command line/target; but again, this'll only help with session cookies.

(Which makes me wonder whether you can set your security so that all cookies are only accepted for the session... but if IE has such settings, they're too well-hidden for me.)